# Excel General and Custom formatting

Tags: excel, formatting

I want to be able to put the string "1 - 2" in an excel cell.  I would be using this string later for other purposes.  As of now if I input "1 - 2" (or "1-2") it turns into "2-Jan" and the cell formatting changes from "General" to "Custom".  If I input "=1-2" I get "-1".  I don't want either of these answers.  I want the string to stay as "1 - 2" and the formatting of the cell to not change.

Is there a way to do make sure the formatting does not change?  Use of VBA code is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format the cell as Text, not General.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  I'm going to hope it's safe to assume that formatting will remain unchanged if I save it and send it to another computer.... because it would be ridiculous if it didn't.  I can't accept this for a few minutes for whatever reason but I will.  Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

You can preface the string with '.

```
'1 - 2
```

Comment: +1, that's really the way to go ;) Changing the format is quite brittle (the format may be altered later, causing unexpected changes), but the `'` is exactly for that purpose and works reliably, as it is stored as part of the cell's data upon saving, and will remain there unless explicitly removed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to put too much into the question so it wouldn't get too confusing.  The "1-2" is an example of something a user might input and it's not reliable that they would put the ' before the equation.  I do appreciate the fast response though, Thank you